# Can't install gatsby-plugin-sharp.(libpng-dev may not installed)

Tags: gatsby

OS: Win 10

windows-build-tools is installed.

When I was trying to install gatsby-plugin-sharp with `npm install --save gatsby-plugin-sharp`. I received two errors.

I've tried this `npm install --save-dev pngquant --msvs_version=2013`  as someone mentioned. But it caused the same error with no 'libpng-dev'.

```
\> mozjpeg@6.0.1 postinstall C:\Users\54391\Documents\code\personal-blog\node_modules\mozjpeg
\> node lib/install.js

‼ getaddrinfo ENOENT raw.githubusercontent.com
‼ mozjpeg pre-build test failed
i compiling from source
× Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "autoreconf -fiv"
'autoreconf' �����ڲ����ⲿ���Ҳ���ǿ����еĳ���
���������ļ���

at C:\Users\54391\Documents\code\personal-blog\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\execa\index.js:231:11
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async Promise.all (index 0)

\> pngquant-bin@5.0.2 postinstall C:\Users\54391\Documents\code\personal-blog\node_modules\pngquant-bin
\> node lib/install.js

‼ getaddrinfo ENOENT raw.githubusercontent.com
‼ pngquant pre-build test failed
i compiling from source
× Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
at C:\Users\54391\Documents\code\personal-blog\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\execa\index.js:231:11
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

Comment: Last week, I changed my dev environment from Windows to WSL to install the plugin. Well, this is not the answer to the problem. But if you have the same issue and still stuck there, I suggest you to try out WSL, which I think is pretty mature these days and it is very easy to setup.